# Problem of connection of turtlebot4 Lite to the Wifi network

Tags: turtlebot, ros-humble

I have acquired a new turtlebot4 Lite. I set up the network by entering the wifi name and passwd using ssh to enter the robot. I changed it from access point mode to client. After that I can't use ssh to enter the robot. I confirmed the robot's IP address on the network using Nmap and it is correct. Although I can use the teleop command to move the robot from my PC terminal, I am unable to access the robot's terminal via ssh.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a firewall on your machine blocking outgoing ssh connections?
If you want to verify the ssh configuration, you could take the memory card from the turtlebot, and read/edit the config file on another machine with a card-reader.